# Is this linear operator $A: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ bounded? If so find its norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$Ax = ((1+\frac{1}{2})x_1,..., (1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{2^n})x_n, ...)$ for $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$

This is an old exam question that I'm trying to work through now.  The coefficients obviously converge to $2$.  Is that fact alone and the fact that $x$ is bounded enough to conclude that $A$ is bounded.

I tried to find the norm by doing:
$\lvert\lvert{A}\rvert\rvert \leq sup_{x\leq1}\lvert\lvert RHS \rvert \rvert = sup_{x\leq1} \lvert\lvert \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ix_i \rvert \rvert = sup_{x\leq1}(\sum a_i^2x_i^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

But now I'm stuck.  I feel like the answer is 2 and that you can get that the norm is less equal 2 and then plug in $(0,...,0,1,0,...)$ where 1's index is large enough and that will give you 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're basically done. Like you said, the coefficients converge to $2$, but moreover, they are bounded above by $2$ as well. Hence,
$$\|Ax\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^k}\right)^2|x_n|^2 \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty 4|x_n|^2 = 4\|x\|^2,$$
thus $\|A\| \le 2$.

The norm is equal to $2$, for exactly the reason you said: compute the image of the $n$th standard basis vector $e^n$, and note that
$$Ae^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^k} \to 2,$$
thus $\|A\| = 2$.